# Find and print three-digit positive integers which the value of the first digit is the sum of 2nd and 3rd ones?

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement

I've tried to separate the last digit and the second one and then add them up to compare with the first. How many loops should I use and how to apply?

I've tried to separate the last digit and the second one and then add them up to compare with the first one.But I don't know how to.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    unsigned int x, counter = 0 ,s = 0, j = 1;
    for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++)
    {
        x = i;
        s = s + (x % 10);
        x = x / 10;
        s = s + (x % 10);
        x = x / 10;
        if (x / 10 == 0)
            break;
        cout << x;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: *"I've tried to separate the last digit and the second one"* -- what do you mean "separate"? I think your question needs more explanation and context (for those who are not able to peer into your mind). Try describing what your intended approach is (even if you don't know how to code it) and why you think it should work. You also might want to review [ask] before editing your question.

Comment: Something that might help the code make more sense to others (and to yourself) is having descriptive variable names. Single-letter names like `s` tend to be trash. Words like `counter` or `sum` are better. Sometimes phrases like `firstDigit` are even better. Comments could also help, perhaps something like `// Extract the second digit.` at the appropriate location in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see some mistakes in the posted attempt.

- The variable `s`, which should represent the sum of the second and third digits, is declared and initialized outside the loop, but its value should be reset to 0 at the beginning of the loop, otherwise it accumulates the value of *all* those digits in *all* the three digits numbers tested.
- the `if (x / 10 == 0) break` line terminates the loop at its *first* iteration. It should neither divide `x`, as it's already the "first" digit, nor test it against 0 (why have you calculated the sum, if you are not using it?), nor break the loop.
- The line `cout << x;` is, well, unreachable (because of the previous test) and wrong, as it prints (or at least tries to) the "first" digit, while the assignment requires to print the three digits numbers that satisfy the rules. So you should (conditionally, when `i == s`) print `i` instead.